# Blurry textures in the viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, 3d-view

I tried to create a Minecraft animation using blender. When I'm in material mode I see this, but when rendering it shows normal.

[image: error with displaying]

Please can anyone tell me what should I do to fix that? I have no idea where that problem is.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Which part of your screenshot isn't as expected by you ? The most important mode is Rendered, that's how object will look like when imported somewhere else. Material mode is approximation and might show some setups not totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the material nodes, on you image texture change linear to closest. This should fix it. Then also try going into material view mode.

Comment: I tried that and it was already set to closest, then I tried to change few other settings but it didnt work. Any other ideas ? Thank you for help.